# iPhone app crashing while application running in background mode

Tags: objective-c

In my app I have implemented following main features:

Manage Contact List.

1.) Fetch the contacts from address book and save them within the app.

2.) Display the list of contacts.

3.) Link the contact with other contact to expand relationship.

Calendar Management

1.) Show the iCal Event within the app & allowing users to create new Events

2.) Show the events on calendar in Day, month & List formats

The memory may have a large memory footprint when it goes to the background. After an extended stay in the background, if I try to revive it, It crashes. This is also random and is not reproducible constantly. Also I have to open the app 2-3 time, before it actually works.

I am inclined to think that as per iOS SDK, an app in the background can be killed by iOS itself if there is a requirement to free up memory for the app which is currently in foreground, so probably that is what is happening, but when I try to relaunch it crashes again 2-3 times. Why would that be happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to use breakpoints at some parts of your app that might use too much memory, and you may find your problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest examining the crash log by

1. connecting your iOS device to your computer,
2. launch Xcode,
3. open the Organizer (Window->Organizer),
4. click on the Devices icon,
5. click on Device Logs.

It may take a few minutes for the log to be fully loaded from your device. The log should tell you where the crash occurred.

Also, if you haven't already done so, add the following code to your view controller.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```